# pull request conflict when making a change by code instead of manually

Tags: git, github, jenkins, npm, versioning

- OS X workstation
- Linux build machine
- GitHub Enterprise

In a Jenkins pipeline, the following works:

1. Manually change the version number in package.json
2. Commit and push
3. Create a pull request from feature branch to develop branch
4. Jenkins checkouts, run tests, npm publishes to a dev scope, and merges
5. Create a pull request from develop branch to master branch
6. Jenkins checkouts, run tests, and npm publishes to a prod scope

If I replace the manual version manipulation to be part of the pipeline by using `npm version patch`, and commit this version change back to the develop branch...

... then once creating the pull request from the develop branch to the master branch, the pull request cannot be created due to a conflict. The conflict appears in the version line in package.json that was changed via the `npm version patch` command.

I am pretty sure it is related to line endings. I do not know how to approach this problem.

Should we change a package's version number manually before deciding to publish, or increment it automatically? Obviously right now the latter will fail due to the above...

---

A solution would be to somehow preserve the line ending of `"version": "0.0.8",` exactly as it were before changing it from .7 to .8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a .gitattributes file with the following has seemingly solved it.

```
*.json text eol=lf
```